# Go back to a Fragment from a ActionBarActivity with the app icon as an up button?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-fragments

I have this GUI to select some Fragments I have in the application. When I select the "Empleados" option, a ListView inside a Fragment appears like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".actividades.admin.InicioAdmin"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </activity>
```

[image: Navigation Drawer]

This is the switch where I inicialize the Fragment.

```
    Fragment fragment = null;

    switch (posicion) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new HomeFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new EmpleadoFragment();
            break;
        case 3:
            UsuarioFunciones.cerrarSesion(context);
            Intent inicio = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            inicio.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(inicio);
            finish();
            Toast.makeText(context,"Sesión finalizada",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame,
                fragment).commit();
        listView.setItemChecked(posicion, true);
        listView.setSelection(posicion);
        setTitle(navMenuTitulos[posicion]);
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(listView);
    }
```

EmpleadoFragment.java (extends Fragment)

[image: Lista]

When selecting an employee, it loads a ActionBarActivity where you can do some functions for that employee.

My question is how can i run the navigation button back to reopen the Fragment where is the ListView?.

[image: Back Button]

When I press the physical "Back" button the ListView is reopened, but with the App Icon not working.

AndroidManifest.xml for the ActionBarActivity above (DetalleEmpleado.java):

```
<activity
    android:name=".actividades.admin.DetalleEmpleado"
    android:label="@string/actividad_detalle_empleado"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:parentActivityName=".SampleParentActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".SampleParentActivity"/>
</activity>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the code to return in the onOptionsItemSelected of your ActionBarActivity.
[Here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#NavigateUp) you can find more information.

```
@Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            //Close current activity
            finish();
        return true;    

         default:
             return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     }
}
```